# Grouping In RDLC/SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am new to SSRS/RDLC reports and I have to create a report . I have two data sets and in the two sets i have an year field I have to group it by year . First dataset 1 should come based on year after that dataset2 should come according to year.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have two options:

A)Use the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) Function to link your two datasets together.

B)Use a subreport(Easier):

Create a three row tablix.

```
Row 1: Column Headers
Row 2: DataSet 1 Data
Row 3: A Subreport.
```

Create a second report for your second dataset. You can then add it into the report by following the steps below.

```
1.Go to insert > Subreport and click on the third row. This will insert the subreport into the tablix.
2.Highlight all the cells in row 3 and press merge.
3.Right click the Sub Report > Properties.
4.In the text box entitle 'Use this report as the subreport' enter the URL from the second report.
```

Comment: When I try to add the contents from dataset 2 I am getting a message like only data from the current dataset "dataset" is allowd

Comment: Edited! Sorry about that.

Comment: No issues... thanks a lot for your time. I will try it and let you know